# How to convert int to xs:gDay?

Tags: c#, xml

How can convert int to string for xml type [gDay](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#gDay)?

Example:

```
var day = 1;
var month = 1;
var year = 2000;

var xElement = new XElement(
    "Day",
    new XAttribute("Day", ConvertToGDay(day)),
    new XAttribute("Month", ConvertToGMonth(month)),
    new XAttribute("Year", ConvertToGYear(year))
);
```

xElement must be so:

```
<Day Day="---01" Month="--01--" Year="2000" />
```

Comment: What *is* `gDay`? There's no such standard type. Your example shows a rather unusual format too. Why don't you write a function that just pads a string with `-` and the number you want? I don't see how this is related to XML

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Not standard, you say? https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#gDay =)

Comment: @J.Steen "never seen a web service or DTO that specifies a recurring date in 20 years" then. Only simple types have built-in mappings so the user will have to write the code to map an integer to this format

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos *That* I can get onboard with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you refer to the XML Schema gDay and gMonth types, which represent events recurring in. According to the specifications for [gDay](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#gDay) and [gMonth](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#gMonth) their representation is `---DD` and `--MM`

You can use [int.ToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t7dwaa5(v=vs.110).aspx)  or [String.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) with [a format string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx) to generate a string padded with dashes, eg:

```
3.ToString("---00")
```

returns `---03` while

```
11.ToString("--00")
```

returns `--11`.

You don't need special formatting for `gYear`, unless you intend to pass years before 1000. In this case, you can use `ToString("0000")`.

The equivalent statements using `String.Format` would be:

```
String.Format("---{0:00}",day);
String.Format("--{0:00}",month);
```

etc, or, by using string interpolation in C# 6,

```
$"---{day:00}"
$"--{month:00}"
```

String.Format allows you to generate the representations for the other types as well, eg for `gMonthDay` you'd use `String.Format("--{0:00}-{1:00}",month,day)` or `$"--{month:00}-{day:00}"`